# Stored procedure cannot creates complex Type

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

This stored procedure when I add to Visual Studio EF database-first cannot create complex type in model browser. The stored procedure returns one column. Why can I not create a complex type?

I added SET FMTONLY OFF not working.

```
    @id int,
    @suay nvarchar(50),
    @suyil nvarchar(50) 
AS 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @deger int; 
    DECLARE @tablo TABLE (price float);

    SET @deger = (SELECT price_second FROM harcamalar  
                  WHERE id = @id AND suay = @suay AND suyil = @suyil);

    INSERT INTO @tablo (price) 
    VALUES (@deger);

    SELECT price FROM @tablo;
END
```

Comment: Why would you expect more than one column? The table variable `@table` only has one column.

Comment: Also, `float` is a terrible choice for something that is called `price`. If you really are storing the price of something, use an exact data type (`decimal`/`int` for example) or the `money` datatype. *Never* use `float` to store the actual prices of things.

Comment: that's because this proc is checking price and i have to read that column using entity framework

Comment: Checking the value has nothing to do with the data type choice.

Comment: ok i changed so do you know the answer why not create complex type or not ?

Comment: And why do you do that insert...select and then select thing? Why not simply select from the source table? `select price_second as price from harcamalar  where id=@id and 
suay =@suay AND suyil =@suyil` will give the exact same result with less than half the code and better performance...

Comment: To be honest, I don't know why you've even declared a table variable in the first place. The entire SP could simply be `select price_second from harcamalar  where id=@id and 
suay =@suay AND suyil =@suyil`. You hugely overly complicate the problem by declaring a table and scalar variable, `SET` the value of the scalar, `INSERT` that into the table variable, and the `SELECT` from that. All those steps are completely pointless.

Comment: @ZoharPeled i tried that way to and not working.i know that code is unnecessary but with or without that code still cannot create complex type

Comment: Your question doesn't explain the problem clearly enough for any of us to answer it correctly. Please try to focus on the problem - Is your problem with the SQL, or is it with EF? If the SQL Doesn't return the result set you're expecting, please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] based on the guidelines in the [sql tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info). If the problem is with EF, please base your [mcve] on the EF code and result set you're getting.

Comment: my question is simple.there is a sql code is working on sql but when add on visual studio using database first EF,simple proc cannot create a complex type.others proc returns but this proc can't.how i can be more specific ? sql code -> work-> ef->can't work ?

Comment: Well, if the problem is on the EF side, why do you show the SQL code (which you claim is working as expected)? Show the part that cause the problem, not the part that works well... BTW, it's still unclear what you mean by "complex type".

Comment: Stored procedures don't "create complex types". That is an error you're getting from EF, and you haven't shown any of the code that's relevant to the error you received.